# References in square brackets

Tags: bibliographies, sv-classes

Here the packages I use in my document:

```
\documentclass[envcountsame,envcountchap]{svmono} 
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}   
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{faktor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage[colorlinks={true},linkcolor={blue},citecolor={blue}]{hyperref}
\usepackage[frame,width=15truecm,height=23.5truecm,center]{crop}
```

Moreover with

```
   \nocite{*}
   \bibliographystyle{alpha}
   \bibliography{mybiblio}
```

in the references I have the labels without square brackets; for example:

> GW10.   bla bla

instead of

> [GW10]   bla bla

I'd like to have the square brackets, can you help me?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the reference style of Springer's `svmono` document class.
Add `oribibl` to its options:

```
\documentclass[envcountsame,envcountchap,oribibl]{svmono} 
...
```

Never used this class, so there might be side effects. Please refer to their class documentation.